# Need to show parent and child from JSON on search in Javascript or Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to show parent and child from Nested JSON data. Please find the following sample JSON data

```
[
        {
            "name": "India",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Delhi",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "South Delhi"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "North Delhi"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Tamil Nadu",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Chennai"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Coimbatore"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "America",
            "chilren": [
                {
                    "name": "California",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Trinity"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Yolo"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Florida",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Bradford"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Calhoun"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

In the above json data. If i search name "**Yolo**" i need to get as America -> California -> Yolo as a result . Can you please help.

Please find the below code i written, This is displaying only child, but i need Parent as well

```
searchRecursive(value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            let lowerCaseName = value[i]['name'].toLowerCase();
            if (lowerCaseName.includes('yolo')) {
                this.searchedItems.push(value[i]);
            } else if (value[i]['children']) {
                if (value[i]['children'].length > 0) {
                    this.searchRecursive(value[i]['children']);
                }
            }
        }

        return this.searchedItems;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Pls find the code i written. This only returns child, i am not able to get Parent

Answer (score 1):

Based on the array you provided you could do something like this:

```
let searchTerm = 'Yolo';

let reduced = countries.reduce((acc, val) => {
  let city = val.children[0].children.filter(city => (city.name == searchTerm)).pop();
  let country = val.name;
  let state = val.children[0].name;

  if (city) {
    return {
      country,
      state,
      city: city.name
    }
  }
});
```

the variable reduce would hold the value:

```
{ country: 'America', state: 'California', city: 'Yolo' }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for all cities:

```
let search = "Chennai";

    const transform = (dArray, parent) => {     
    return dArray.map(item => [item.children, item.name, parent]);
    }

    transformed = [].concat.apply([], (data.map(contry => transform(contry.children,contry.name))));
    transformed2 = [].concat.apply([], (transformed.map(item => transform(item[0], item[1]))));

    query1 = transformed2.filter(item => item[1] === search); 
    query2 = transformed.filter(item => item[1] === query1[0][2])

   console.log(query2[0][2] + ' -> ' + query1[0][2] + ' -> ' + query1[0][1])
```

It's ugly but it works. The idea is to transform the data to two data structures

**transformed:**

```
(4) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
0: (3) [Array(2), "Delhi", "India"]
1: (3) [Array(2), "Tamil Nadu", "India"]
2: (3) [Array(2), "California", "America"]
3: (3) [Array(2), "Florida", "America"]
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**transformed2:**

```
(8) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
0: (3) [undefined, "South Delhi", "Delhi"]
1: (3) [undefined, "North Delhi", "Delhi"]
2: (3) [undefined, "Chennai", "Tamil Nadu"]
3: (3) [undefined, "Coimbatore", "Tamil Nadu"]
4: (3) [undefined, "Trinity", "California"]
5: (3) [undefined, "Yolo", "California"]
6: (3) [undefined, "Bradford", "Florida"]
7: (3) [undefined, "Calhoun", "Florida"]
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)
```

And then join the two structures with the .filter functions. Town  name must be unique for it to work